# Testing an abstract method of a child-class from an abstract class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, abstract-class

To stay with the same example I used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071435/stubbing-a-method-called-in-the-constructor-of-an-abstract-class):

I now want to test the implementation of the protected methods in my child-classes.
Because I stub them in my test of the abstract class, the implementations themselves aren't tested.
But a protected-method isn't tested normally, so that's why I'd like your suggestions on how to test them after all.

Just like [my other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071435/stubbing-a-method-called-in-the-constructor-of-an-abstract-class) I'd like to solve this **without refactoring my code**.

Parent-class:

```
abstract class Order
{
    public function __construct( $orderId, User $user )
    {
        $this->id = $this->findOrderId( $user->getId(), $orderId );

        if ($this->id !== false) {
            $this->setOrderData();
        }
    }

    abstract protected function findOrderId( $userId, $orderIdToSearch );

    private function setOrderData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Child-class to test:

```
public class OrderTypeA extends Order
{
    protected function findOrderId($userId, $orderId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
class OrderTypeATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testFindOrderId() {
        ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test protected/private methods using the reflection. Read this [tutorial](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-3-testing-protected-private-methods-coverage-reports-and-crap/). There you will find, among the other solutions, the direct one:

```
/**
 * Call protected/private method of a class.
 *
 * @param object &$object    Instantiated object that we will run method on.
 * @param string $methodName Method name to call
 * @param array  $parameters Array of parameters to pass into method.
 *
 * @return mixed Method return.
 */
 public function invokeMethod(&$object, $methodName, array $parameters = array())
 {
     $reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
     $method = $reflection->getMethod($methodName);
     $method->setAccessible(true);

     return $method->invokeArgs($object, $parameters);
 }
```

Also, regarding the previous question of yours, where you are trying to test abstract class. The solution with phpunit mocking must work. But if you use PHP 7, you can use [Anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) to achieve the same result:

```
abstract class Order
{
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($orderId, $userId)
    {
        $this->id = $this->findOrderId($userId, $orderId);

        if ($this->id !== false) {
            $this->setOrderData();
        }
    }

    abstract protected function findOrderId($userId, $orderIdToSearch);

    private function setOrderData()
    {
        echo 'setOrderData';
    }
}

$orderId = 1;
$userId = 1;

$order = new class($orderId, $userId) extends Order {
    protected function findOrderId($userId, $orderIdToSearch)
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

You will end up with the working **$order** object, which is ready for testing. Also it is good idea to put this code in the **setUp()** method of the Test Case.

Comment: Thanks this really helped me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only get a valid `$this->id` when a order is found right. Do some like:

```
$order = new OrderTypeA($orderId, $user);
$this->assertNotEquals(false,$order->id);
```

Or if `$orderId` equals `$this->id`

```
$order = new OrderTypeA($orderId, $user);
$this->assertEquals($orderId,$order->id);
```

But not enough code/logic  shown here to tell you more;)

Comment: The `findOrderId` method only returns the id (= `$orderId` if found) or `null` if not found

Comment: Then this `if ($this->id !== false) ` must be `if ($this->id !== NULL) ` in the first place

Comment: And you can use the OR Part of my answer, maybe you should throw an Exception if no $orderID was found, to handle this case right; And normally you will not do this in the _constructor.

Comment: Maybe make an public  `findOrderById` to move the stuff out of the constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry it returns `false` if not found

Answer (score 0):

Your abstraction does not make sense to me.

I understand that you have an object representing an order. You instantiate it by giving a user and an order id. However there's more than one type of order, and the difference between these types of orders is in the way you search them in the database storage? That doesn't sound right.

Your code does tell a weird story. You have this order id, and the first thing you do is search the order id. I just thought that you already HAVE the order id, so there shouldn't be a need to yet again search for it. Or maybe that method has the wrong name, and instead of `findOrderId()` it should be called `findOrderById()` - or `findUserOrderById()`.

Also, you do work in the constructor. Searching for stuff should not be done there.

Your testing problem comes from the fact that you decided to implement different search strategies as an abstract method. You have to test a protected abstract method, which is not really easy. It makes it also hard to property test the main abstract order class because you have to provide an implementation - and this implementation sounds like it conceals a database access layer, so there can be plenty of things going wrong in the real code.

I suggest not allowing the order to search itself. Searching for orders should be done outside of the order object. That way, you'll likely implement that search as a public method, which can be normally tested. The code searching for orders will then decide whether you have a successfully found `OrderTypeA`, or maybe a missing `MissingOrderTypeA`, both extending the order class. The order objects should carry the order data, not the search logic to find them in the database.

Hint: If you have problems testing your code, it is 99,9% likely that your code is trying to do things the wrong way. This is not saying that things cannot be done that way, it is saying that you are about to produce hard to test code, that is also hard to maintain, and that it is a good idea to look for alternative strategies to implement the solution. Elegant code is always easy to test, because all the necessary methods are public in the relevant classes, and therefore can work together as intended.

Comment: The `findOrderId` method is just an extra check to see if the given ID is from a real Order, so you don't have to set all the data if it isn't. In this case I'd also like to **not** change my code, just test it.